# Will users get access to sensitive data with this database retrieve method?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making a dating app. Currently, I have a "feed" that's getting data off of the node "users" (database image below):

The node has the users: email, name, and birthday..etc. I only want users to have access to other users name.  If I leave my data structure as is, will users be able to somehow get the user's birthday? How? If I don't display it at all on my app?

[image]

Fetch value code

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        FIRApp.configure()
        
        refArtists = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users");
        
        //observing the data changes
        refArtists.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            
            //if the reference have some values
            if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
                
                //clearing the list
                self.artistList.removeAll()
                
                //iterating through all the values
                for artists in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                    //getting values
                    let artistObject = artists.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                    let artistName  = artistObject?["name"]
                    let artistId  = artistObject?["id"]
                    let artistGenre = artistObject?["interest"]
                    
                    //creating artist object with model and fetched values
                    let user = ArtistModel(id: artistId as! String?, name: artistName as! String?, genre: artistGenre as! String?)
                    
                    //appending it to list
                    self.artistList.append(user)
                }
                
                //reloading the tableview
                self.tableViewArtists.reloadData()
            }
        })
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not a production DB structure, Be very careful with firebase database and public access, Firebase usually sends out emails for un-secure rules.

In the real world, If your app manages to go viral and catch eyes, Jailbroken Devices will come into play.

A jailbroken device with an equipped modern file manager can get your database credentials, This is safe and dangerous.

Safe When:

- You want a easy setup for you and your project and firebase
- You have a well written rule that will deny incoming requests from unwanted access
- You have a good database structure (See [Firebase: Structure Your Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data)

**Not Safe When:**

- You don't have secure Firebase Access Rules
- You have a bad database structure and grouping, an attackers hope.
- You read everything at once.

Recommended Steps:

Use the real world Firebase security rules, they're fast, secure, and does not require an app update, so you can make changes at any time of the day.

Firebase Rules:
[Understand Firebase Realtime Database Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security)